# Is there a word to describe when an argument is pulled to the same topic

Tags: single-word-requests

I often end up debating politics and the general state of the world with a friend, however, the friend now believes that all issues are related to essentially 2 root causes. It is now at the point where no matter which topic we open for discussion, the discussion will be short circuited within minutes to 1 or both of these 2 root issues.

Needless to say, this doesn't leave for a very rich conversation or debate.

Is there a word to describe this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might say the person has a *pet issue* that they tie everything else back to.

> It's not that you people are wrong, it's that you refuse to let any
> discussion take place without injecting your **pet issue** into the
> conversation; you are why we can't have nice things. (Oklahoma Doctors
> vs. Obamacare - [Reason.com](http://reason.com/reasontv/2012/11/15/the-obamacare-revolt-oklahoma-doctors-fi), 2012)

Another way of saying it is a *hobbyhorse*

[ADH](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hobbyhorse)

> A topic that one frequently brings up or dwells on; a fixation.

> The number of people provoked by this act, this post, who jump on
> their **hobbyhorse** of AA or Suicide Hotlines and start the go! team! go!
> chant are more interested in salving their consciences or confirming
> their life choices than they are about this poor, dead man. Joe would
> not have made it nearly as far as he did without the benefit of
> alcohol. Suicide is always the escape hatch of the artist. We each
> choose the manner of our living; we each choose the manner of our
> leaving. Do not judge me until you know what I know ([blog comments](https://qualityshows.wordpress.com/2011/12/23/if-this-were-y0ur-last-day-alive-what-would-you-do/))

A person like this might be characterized as *self-serving*

[ADH](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=self-serving)

> adj.
>
> 1. Serving one's own interests, especially without concern for the needs or interests of others.
> 2. Exhibiting concern solely for one's own interests: *a speech full of self-serving comments*.

Even if there's not a single word out there for it, the above may help in the description of the situation.

> My self-serving friend short-circuits all our conversations by
> trotting out one of his two hobbyhorses.